# CI3 vs PHPixie vs YII2 vs Laravel vs CakePHP vs Phalcon

Tags: php, php-frameworks

Здравствуйте. Выбираю фреймворк для подальшей работы с ним и наметил себе несколько из них: CI3, PHPixie, Yii2, Laravel, CakePHP, Phalcon. Все они хороши, но нету нормальных сравнений, отзывов. Хочу узнать все минусы/плюсы последних версий данных фреймворков от тех, кто с ними работает.

PS: Да, я искал в интернете предельно хорошо и тут тоже, именно того, что мне нужно, в одном стиле - нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще вопрос довольно широкий, и его скорее всего закроют в виду зависимости от мнения конкретного человека.

Давайте просто возьмем классические ошибки, которые есть в этих фреймворках

> CI3

- Отстутствие контейнера
- Блевотно-офторматированный код
- Отсутствие автозагрузки
- Файлы фреймворка лежат внутри публичной папки
- Конфигурация через PHP-файлы
- Насколько понимаю, отсутствует шаблонизатор
- Насколько понимаю, неймспейсы пока еще не снизошли благодатью на этот фреймворк

> PHPixie

- Отсутствие контейнера
- Является микрофреймворком, и расширять его довольно проблематично
- Все остальное терпимо

> Yii2

Yii - это отдельная тема. Эти люди всегда хотят как лучше, выбирают один из лучших ориентиров, а потом делают извержение ада, которым, вроде, должно быть удобно пользоваться, потому что для этого все сделано, с другой стороны, проект всегда превращается в единый безудержный костыль

- (+) Есть контейнер
- (-) В виду наличия богообъекта непонятно, зачем он там нужен
- Все делается через какие-то идиотские расширения, автоматизация если и будет, то к третьей версии
- Никто до сих пор не знает, как выглядит правильный модуль
- Конфигурация в виде PHP-файлов
- За каким-то чертом приложение обязано существовать в неймспейсе `app`
- Отсутствие шаблонизатора (хотя твиг легко прикручивается)
- Труднозаменимый ActiveRecord

> Laravel

Самый достойный из перечисленных. Толком не работал с ним, WTF-моментов полно, но выглядит не так ужасно.

- Конфигурация в виде PHP-файлов
- Пятьдесят файлов пустого приложения, из которых двадцать - конфигурация. Я не шучу.
- Конфигурация роутинга через вызовы методов фиксированного класса. Это просто несерьезно.
- Все на статических методах, в результате проще не прострелить себе ногу, чем по-человечески оттестировать приложение. Я видел, как люди оборачивают модели в репозитории, чтобы это обойти.
- Труднозаменимый ActiveRecord
- Как итог - myötähäpeä

> CakePHP

Думал, что такой же мамонт, как и CI, но оказался получше

- конфигурация в PHP-файлах

> Phalcon

Забавное творение с очередным баулом wtf-ситуаций, баги сильно портят работу, т.к. для нормальной работы требуется ждать, пока фиксы выльются в апстрим. Из чтения документации удивило то, что автозагрузку они предлагают не PSR-совместимую. Ну и, конечно

- конфигурация в PHP- или INI-файлах, ни тебе yml, ничего удобного и нормального

Из предложенного списка я бы выбрал либо Phalcon, либо Laravel. Из непредложенного есть еще Zend (по нему у меня нет знаний) и Symfony 2, от которой временами тоже тянет сходить к доктору, но на фоне всего остального она выглядит просто блестяще, хоть и порог вхождения у нее соответствующий.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такое "разжевывание". Я так и думал что Phalcon/Lavarel вытащат. Еще меня тянет yii не смотря на все его минусы, из-за его простоты. На Зенд я смотрел - не то. Симфони тоже хорош, но... но меня убивает то, что, например, для валидации формы нужно вставить NotBlank куда можно и нельзя. В yaml, в php, в xml, в аннотации к php.. в то время как в том-же yii автоматически все генерируется.

Comment: Симфони вообще другая. Там валидируется не форма и не модель, там валидируется объект. То есть, фактически, там уничтожена обязательная привязка к моделям, вебу и вообще всему в принципе. За счет этого она и выигрывает - средняя скорость разработки ниже, но как только начинаются непредвиденные ситуации, симфони показывает себя значительно лучше остальных фв.

Comment: _Симфони вообще другая. Там валидируется не форма и не модель, там валидируется объект._ А человеческими словами? =)

Comment: В симфони может быть осуществлена валидация чего угодно. В Yii - только модели. Если в API приходит хитрая закорюка, для которой не соответствует ни одна модель, или там несколько моделей, то симфони с такой задачей справится без гигантских проблем (она даже понимает вложенные сущности), а вот Yii в этот момент знатно просядет.

Comment: я тут посмотрел на стартер-темплейты симфони и пробежался по статьям - наверное для новичка и для меня, перфекциониста, symfony - не то, но все равно спасибо!!! =)

О, теперь я понял о чем вы. Но мне симфони не угодила все-равно)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Trends: Codeigniter, PHPixie, Yii2, Laravel, CakePHP, Phalcon](https://www.google.ru/trends/explore#q=Codeigniter%2C%20PHPixie%2C%20Yii2%2C%20Laravel%2C%20CakePHP%2C%20Phalcon)

See also: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426262/179379